# React Router - hide header and footer when rendered in iFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-router

I have a react app built with create-react-app. This is my index.js

```
export class MyRoutes extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
                <Route path='/team' component={ Team }/>
                <Route path='/career' component={ Career }/>
                <Route path='/faq' component={ Faq }/>
                <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact }/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/jobs' component={ JobHome } />
                    <Route path='/jobs/alle' component={ JobList } />
                    <Route path='/jobs/:url' component={ JobDescription } />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Responsive minWidth={768}>
                <Header/>
                <MyRoutes/>
            </Responsive>

            <Responsive maxWidth={767}>
                <MobileHeader
                    routes={<MyRoutes/>}
                />
            </Responsive>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I need the url `/jobs/:url` to be rendered in an iframe on an external website.
How do I exclude the `<Header/>` and `<Footer/>` on this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution finally worked for me:

```
const MyRoutes = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
        <Route path='/team' component={ Team }/>
        <Route path='/career' component={ Career }/>
        <Route path='/faq' component={ Faq }/>
        <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact }/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/jobs' component={ JobHome } />
            <Route path='/jobs/alle' component={ JobList } />
            <Route path='/jobs/:url' component={ JobDescription } />
        </Switch>
        <Route path='/xing_jobs/:url' component={ JobDescription }/>
    </div>
)

export let App = (props) => {
    let location = props.location;
    let isXingUrl = location.pathname && location.pathname.match(/^\/xing_jobs/);
    console.log('isXingUrl', isXingUrl);

    return (
        <div>
            <Responsive minWidth={768}>
                {!isXingUrl && <Header/>}
                <MyRoutes/>
            </Responsive>

            <Responsive maxWidth={767}>
                <MobileHeader
                    showHeader={!isXingUrl}
                    routes={<MyRoutes/>}
                />
            </Responsive>
            {!isXingUrl && <Footer/>}
        </div>
    )
}
App = withRouter(App);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like the right way is to put you mobile header inside you router:

```
<Route path="/jobs/..." component={ComponentwithoutHeader}>
<Route path="/" component={Header}>
...Routes wit header
</>
```

In your header component use this to render the nested components.
{this.props.children}

So that way you can use a same component to Header and Footer, and render the body between this two.

Tell if it worked. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
export class MyRoutes extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let {path} = this.props.matc
        let routes = (
            <div>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/team' component={Team}/>
                <Route path='/career' component={Career}/>
                <Route path='/faq' component={Faq}/>
                <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
                <Route exact path='/jobs' component={JobHome}/>
                <Route path='/jobs/alle' component={JobList}/>
                <Route path='/jobs/:url' component={JobDescription}/>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
        )
        return (
          <div>
            <Responsive minWidth={768}>
                {path != '/jobs/:url' && <Header/>}
                {routes}
            </Responsive>

            <Responsive maxWidth={767}>
                <MobileHeader
                    routes={routes}
                />
            </Responsive>
            {path != '/jobs/:url' && <Footer/>}
        </div>
        )
    }
}




ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ MyRoutes }/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: With this only the `/`route works. The remaining pages cannot render their content

Comment: The problem was `exact path='/'`. Without `exact` it works. However the path is always `/` and thus the tertiary operator does not work.

Comment: can you try it now.. I added the <Switch> and moved the / route to the end

Comment: No, also not. Now the content does not get rendered. Only Header and Footer are rendered.

Comment: the problem is that `props.match` are not passed on to the `<Router/>`. Please see my answer for a working fix.